# Subsetting a spacetime::SDFDF by time

Tags: r, subset, r-sp

***How can I subset a `spacetime::SDFDF` (spatio-temporal data with full space-time grid) by time?***

Sofar, I tried:

```
library("maps")
library("maptools")
library("spacetime")
library("plm")

states.m <- map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE)
IDs <- sapply(strsplit(states.m$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
states <- map2SpatialPolygons(states.m, IDs = IDs)
yrs <- 1970:1986
time <- as.POSIXct(paste(yrs, "-01-01", sep = ""), tz = "GMT")
data("Produc")

Produc.st <- STFDF(states[-8], time, Produc[order(Produc[2], Produc[1]),])
Produc.st@time[c(1,5,17)]
Produc.st[Produc.st@time[c(1,5,17)]]
```

But that gives me the `error: ncol(i) == 2 is not TRUE`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
Produc.st[,index(Produc.st@time[c(1,5,17)])]
```

i.e., time selection is done after the `,`, and don't select with an `xts` object as `Produc.st@time[c(1,5,17)])` is, but with a time (`POSIXct`) vector.